# Where do you hear The National?

Tags: portal-2

I seem to recall stumbling across a radio playing something fairly uncharacteristic for the normal Portal music, in an overgrown chamber if I recall correctly, but I can't find it anymore; what chamber (or map) was it in?

I think it was the song by The National, Exile Vilify, that is in the game.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59oSNeRvZUI&feature=related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Test Chamber 03 after Glados wakes up, it's playing from a radio in the semi-secret behind-the-scenes area connected to this room.